# Powershell - How do I find dll's not found by process?

Tags: windows, powershell

So using Procmon, there is a section called "Result" that let's you see whether the dll for a specific process was loaded successfully or if it was "not found". I'm wondering if there is a way to find results like this in powershell?

I know how to find a list of dll's a process is using in powershell, but I don't know how to list any dll's that the process tried to load, but couldn't find. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: ProcMon gathers this information at runtime by 'monitoring' the process activity, (hence 'process monitor') and it isn't stored anywhere else.  If a process really can't find a DLL it needs, I'd expect it to fail with an error and not just carry on.  If you are seeing this with a process, it is possible/likely that the 'fail' is due to the default [DLL Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) meaning that Windows doesn't find the DLL in the first place it looks, but finds it later.

Comment: As for this.. 'but I don't know how to list any dll's that the process tried to load, but couldn't find.' … you really couldn't, because garbage collection would dispose of them when they are no longer needed, and there is no record of that unless you are trapping that in code as it happens. You cannot do that natively with PowerShell, you'll have to call C/C#/<net libraries and memory management to get them. Not an easy task.